# Selecting time in prompt alert ionic-2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm new to ionic-2. I'm developing an app, where the user will have to create alarms. For that, I've created a page. that page contains a '+' button. When that button is clicked, a prompt alert appears. As of now, that prompt alert has a text-box and ok buttons. But, instead of that I need to display a datetime picker. How can I do that? any help?

```
my html file:
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Alarm</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-fab right bottom>
        <button ion-fab (click)="alarm()" color="vibrant" mini>
            <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-fab>
</ion-content>

my ts file:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-wifi-controller-schedules',
  templateUrl: 'wifi-controller-schedules.html'
})
export class AlarmsPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {}



  alarm() {
    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Login',
      message: "Enter a name for this new album you're so keen on adding",
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'title',
          placeholder: 'Title'
        },
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Save',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Saved clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    prompt.present();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

for a datepicker you could probably just add `type = 'date'` to your `input` object (within `inputs`)

```
inputs: [
        {
          name: 'title',
          placeholder: 'Title',
          type: 'date'
        },
      ],
```

But this doesn't come in `HH24:mm` format so it will be a datepicker...

Like [Mike Harrington](https://forum.ionicframework.com/users/mhartington) said in an answer on [this issue](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/creating-custom-alerts-in-ionic2/49723) the end goal of the alert is not for doing these kind of things.

But since the navigation stack stacks a modal on top of a page, you can just create a **Modal** ([docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/ModalController/)), give it a bit of padding, set a background of `rgba(0,0,0,0.85)` and close the modal with your data (or call a service, not sure about your usecase) when the user presses a button/closes the page.

So, if you create a child-page (with the time-picker) named `Page1` with a selector of `page1` you can just add the following css:

```
page1.modal {
    padding: 30px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

And then create a modal of the page like

```
import { ModalController } from 'ionic/angular';
import { Page1 } from './page1.component';
.......

constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) { ... }

showModal() {
   let timepickModal = this.modalCtrl.create(Page1);
   timepickModal.present();
}

.....
```

CSS and image from  [Custom Modal Alert with HTML Form](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/custom-modal-alert-with-html-form/47980/4)

[image]

**edit**

If you want to pass data from the second page (the modal) to the first page (parent), you can use ionic's [Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/) (one of my favorite components)

Parent page: (within `ngOnInit` or `constructor` f.e.)

```
events.subscribe('time:created', time) => {
  // time is passed from modal to here, add it to list.
  myTimeList.push(time);
});
```

Modal page: (after selecting time/submitting value)

```
events.publish('time:created', someObjectHoldingTime);
```

(import : `import { Events } from 'ionic/angular';`)

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. But, the above method is static. Can it be designed dynamically, so that I can select a time and add to a list dynamically. Literally like creating an alarm?

Comment: edited the answer with *my* best practice of passing back and forth data in Ionic. this way you can have a list in your parent page, and select a time from your second page.

Comment: just curious, why not viewCtrl.dismiss(time)?

Comment: @SurajRao Could be used as well (probably, no experience with it), I prefer using `Events` for flexibility, if you want to add a time from another page for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
inputs: [
        {
          type: 'date',
          name: 'title',
          placeholder: 'Title'
        },
      ]
```

seems to work in the browser.
You could try to adjust it with `cssClass` property.
I would go with [popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/popover/PopoverController/) though.

Comment: U have an example for this using popover?

Comment: not at the moment. you can easily add https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/datetime/DateTime/ to the template of a page and create with popover

Comment: it shows the default html input as date picker type in the browser..for me

Comment: alert is not meant for complex input types.. https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/alert/AlertController/