# ionic 3 - implement datepicker in actionsheet

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I am new to ionic 3 and I am looking for a solution to implement `datepicker` in `actionsheet`.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

I am also open to get any other suggestions if you have to achieve the same output showing in the image linked.

Thank you so much for attention.

Comment: By briefly looking at the documentation I don't think an `ActionSheet` is capable of this. Your best bet will be to create the desired page yourself and show it with `ModalController` or even better with `PopoverController` (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/)

Comment: @Ivaro18 I also think the same about `ActionSheet`. Thank you for the suggestion, I am thinking to try `ModalController` to achieve it if I can customize the height of `Modal`. BTW.. thanks for the help and attention.

Comment: You can actually change the height and make a `Modal` look like a popup. Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263123/selecting-time-in-prompt-alert-ionic-2/41263785#41263785

Comment: So helpful. Thank you so much for the great help :) :)

Answer (score -1):

## View

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Start Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime  displayFormat="MMM DD YYYY" [(ngModel)]="start_date"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

## https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/action-sheet/

Comment: I am aware about it but I want to show it in actionsheet.